# content that has slice

Tags: html, css

I have a design [here](http://prntscr.com/6wpkle). I got 1 div with 2 div for the content inside so basically this will be the structure.

```
<div class="block">
<div class="slice1"></div>
<div class="slice2"></div>
</div>
```

how can I do the slice thing for the 2 content? I can't use a whole background image for the whole div since it will not be responsive on smaller windows. 
is this possible using border radius?

fiddle here: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e85cLgra/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the CSS `:after` pseudo-class, draw a triangle using borders, float it right, etc.  I think the code is self-explanatory, but let me know if you have questions:

```
.slice1:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:10px;
    height:200px;
    float:right;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 200px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid blue;
    margin-right:-30px;
    position:relative;
}
```

A little bonus: to make it disappear in responsive, use @media selectors:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .slice1, .slice2 {
    width:100%;
  }
  .slice1:after {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e85cLgra/2/